# Modernizing auth options for a .NET framework 4.7.2 era project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a legacy solution that is comprised of a ASP.NET Web application with MVC controllers and a web api.  It also has some supporting class library projects and 3rd party libraries for things like pdf generation.  All of the projects target .NET Framework 4.7.2.  Its pretty basic stuff.

With all of the terminology floating around (.NET, .NET Framework, .NET Core, ASP.NET, ASP.NET CORE, .NET Standard, etc) I don't know exactly how to speak about the correct technology stack.  I think given the era (2012-2014) and the assemblies I see referenced I think the correct way to refer to the tech would be ASP.NET application utilizing MVC 5 (I see package Microsoft.AspNet.MVC @ version 5.0 referenced).  Maybe it should be called an ASP.NET 5 application?

The reason I'm trying to figure this out is that I cant tell what my potential technology options are for libraries I can add to my web app with respect to authentication.  Right now its using forms authentication with a session cookie and the Startup file is almost entirely blank (it only includes a "app.MapSignalR();" that I assume someone had to add at some point when they were adding SignalR to the project.  This was the era of "membership" and web.config settings for System.Web.

I see many modern approaches where the Startup file will include app.UseAuthentication() or app.AddX() code and I think that means they utilize a OWIN middleware or pipeline?  Is this the most modern that a .NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting app can hope to utilize what is this called so I know how to drop in the required dependencies to change this aspect of my app?

The history and naming of all this tech is impenetrable and really confusing hoping someone has an idea of what my options are or can assist in identifying the correct technology terminology so I can research with more confidence.

EDIT:

- Wanted to mention the web app is hosted in IIS and is not something I'm looking to change.
- I see some OWIN package references for "Microsoft.Owin.Host.System.Web" @ version 2.0.2 (seems quite old comparing to whats on nuget.org).  Also see "Microsoft.Owin" package @ version 2.0.2 referenced as well.

Comment: Throw it all out and start again. Seriously. The state of the art has evolved so much since MVC 5 that trying to shoehorn modern auth flows into an old app like that is going to achieve nothing but pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding that the key term I was missing was "ASP.NET Identity" in MVC5.  This is the evolution of authentication/authorization for ASP.NET websites that required OWIN pipeline.  The default project template at the time included the appropriate identity and authentication related types as well as the OWIN related types necessary to tie these features into the request pipeline.  The types included will then let you integrate with an openid connect authentication server, facebook/twitter/google, etc.